# QT5 cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const QThread' with expression of type 'name1Thread'

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm getting the error:

cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const QThread' with an expression of type 'name1Thread'

A snippet of code from my header file, called 'name1.h':

```
#include <QThread>

...

class name1;
class name1Thread : public QThread
 {
      Q_OBJECT

public:
   
 void stop()
    {
        if(this->isRunning())   //Error occurs here            
        {
             mRunning = false;
             mCondition.notify_one();
         }
    }
```

I don't understand why this isn't working; please help.

Comment: Is the error pointing to this code? I bet it's pointing to a use of name1Thread. Can you include that?

Comment: The error in question is pointing to the line of the if-statement. I can't really trace it any further back than that.

Comment: Without something resembling code someone could compile, it's hard to help. Can you produce a minimal example? That error usually references a class that can't be instantiated because it's pure virtual or because of constructor issues, so it makes no sense on that if. Plop enough code in that I can stick it into a blank Qt program.